# Mongoose populate in feathers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm new in node and I'm using Feathersjs.
I'm trying to use mongoose populate to do the relation between `users` and `tasks`

My models:

`user-model.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
password: { type: String, required: true },
tasks: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Task' }],
createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
updatedAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
});

var Task = mongoose.model('Task', storySchema);
const userModel = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = userModel;
```

`task-model.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const taskSchema = new Schema({
title: { type: String, required: true },
_creator : { type: String, ref: 'User' },
createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
updatedAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
});

var User = mongoose.model('user', storySchema);
const taskModel = mongoose.model('task', taskSchema);

module.exports = taskModel;
```

When I add a new Task, user.tasks still empty:

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5832da6919756a0edc2dfc59"),
    "email" : "igorpollo@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$DToGYQ8smdfsK4oJPXmcyOdIfxXEaQGO5P16AhzBlrpESUMt5baNi",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-11-21T11:28:41.371Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-11-21T11:28:41.371Z"),
    "tasks" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
  }
 > db.tasks.find().pretty()
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5832da7619756a0edc2dfc5a"),
    "title" : "test",
    "_creator" : "5832da6919756a0edc2dfc59",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-11-21T11:28:54.470Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-11-21T11:28:54.470Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: How do you fill in the data? I think that the error is related to that section. Please provide more information, so we can solve this :)

Answer (score 2):

*I know it is an old post. I am answering incase it helps anyone.*

First of all, the code above doesn't show how you are inserting data.

This way you can populate in FeathersJS. Tested in version `4.3.4`

```
before: {
  ...,
  create: [(ctx) => {
    ctx.app.service('users').find({
      query: {
        $populate: ['tasks']
      }
    });
  }
}]
```

**OR,**

Inside hook, you can get access to your mongoose model like this (Ex: before create hook):

```
before: {
  ...,
  create: [(ctx) => {
    const UserModel = ctx.app.service('users').Model;
  }
}]
```

Now you should be able to populate `tasks` like this: `UserModel.find({}).populate('tasks')`

**OR,**

if you are in service class where you have access to `app`, you can get the model like this:
`app.service('users').Model` and then run the same populate query shown above.

Comment: So the relation is built on create not on find?
I didn't populate them previously, now how do I do the query?

Answer (score -1):

There are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections as in your use case. This is where population comes in.

So, you may try it using `mongoose` as follow:

```
User                  // Mongoose model
 .find({})
 .populate('tasks')   // Populate referenced attributes
 .exec()              // Executes the query and return Promise
```

Read more about population in mongoose:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html